# Nested observablecollection to list, how to keep order?

Tags: c#, list, observablecollection

I have several `observablecollection` inside one `observablecollection` (VideoFileName). They contain objects of the same type that have two properties `FileName`(string) and `FileIsSelected`(bool).

I want to have all of them inside only one List (`SelectedVideoNames`), but the `FileNameshould` must be added to the list only if `FileIsSelected` is true.

Here is my code:

```
List<string> DefaultSelectedVideoNames = new List<string> { "empty" };
List<string> SelectedVideoNames = new List<string> { };

for (var j = 0; j < ChannelsCount; j++)
{
    if (uiElement.VideoFileNames[j].Count == 0)
        {
            MessageOutput.AddFrom("SelectedVideoNames", DefaultSelectedVideoNames);
        }
        else
        {
            for (var k = 0; k < uiElement.VideoFileNames[j].Count; k++)
            {
                if (uiElement.VideoFileNames[j][k].FileIsSelected == true)
                {
                    SelectedVideoNames.Add(uiElement.VideoFileNames[j][k].FileName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when `FileIsSelected` value is changed, it will be added to the end of the list, But I would like to keep the order of the original `observablecollection`.

How can I do that?

A little schema might explain my problem better :

```
(observablecollection) Video Selector 0
    --->Video (FileName = "John", FileIsSelected = "true")
    --->Video (FileName = "Dany", FileIsSelected = "false")
    --->Video (FileName = "Bob", FileIsSelected = "true")
    ...

(observablecollection) Video Selector 1
    --->Video (FileName = "Henry", FileIsSelected = "false")
    --->Video (FileName = "Jack", FileIsSelected = "false")
    --->Video (FileName = "Chris", FileIsSelected = "false")
    ...

(observablecollection) Video Selector 2
    --->Video (FileName = "Jimmy", FileIsSelected = "true")
    --->Video (FileName = "Tim", FileIsSelected = "true")
    --->Video (FileName = "Donald", FileIsSelected = "true")
    ...
```

Final list should be

```
John, Bob, Jimmy, Tim, Donald
```

At runtime for example, the video called "Dany" has FileIsSelected set to true so the list becomes :

```
John, Dany, Bob, Jimmy, Tim, Donald
```

But now I get something like this :

```
John, Bob, Jimmy, Tim, Donald, Dany
```

Comment: I believe you'll have to either look for a proper place in a list to add this item, or to sort the entire list after each change. Anyway you'll have to do it manually.

Comment: Why multiple lists inside a list?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary that's not list inside list, just one. But from an observablecollection of observablecollection : uiElement.VideoFileName" WITHOUT not selected items

Comment: added a little schema, hope it helps to understand what I'm trying to achieve